# jquery $.getjSON don't reach to callbackfunction

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to proccess a jSON request, the url used in getJSON is

```
http://localhost:52563/Documentos/Docs/CondicionesMostrar?NumIdTransaccion=16091&NumIdConcepto=421.
```

The text returned by my partialview using this:

```
string ljListaItems = Json.Encode(loListaItems).ToString();
@ljListaItems
```

it return this data

```
    [{"MedidasRelativas":false,"CssClass":"ParadigmaNTouchItem","CssClassAlterna":"ParadigmaNTouchItemAlterno","CssClassImage":"","CssClassTitle":"","CssClassFlag":"","ajaxRegion":"DetalleCondiciones","ajaxAction":"onclick=\"/Documentos/Docs/CondicionesAgregar?NumIdtransaccion=16090&IntIdCondicion=1&status=False\"","ajaxActionIzq":"","ajaxEnabled":true,"ajaxMethod":0,"ajaxMode":0,"ajaxRegionLoading":"#trabajando","ajaxData":"","image":"","editarCantidad":false,"cantidad":0,"useCssAlterno":false,"id":"I_Cond_1","title":"sin pulpo","flag":null,"width":0,"height":0,"top":0,"left":0},{"MedidasRelativas":false,"CssClass":"ParadigmaNTouchItem","CssClassAlterna":"ParadigmaNTouchItemAlterno","CssClassImage":"","CssClassTitle":"","CssClassFlag":"","ajaxRegion":"DetalleCondiciones","ajaxAction":"onclick=\"/Documentos/Docs/CondicionesAgregar?NumIdtransaccion=16090&IntIdCondicion=2&status=False\"","ajaxActionIzq":"","ajaxEnabled":true,"ajaxMethod":0,"ajaxMode":0,"ajaxRegionLoading":"#trabajando","ajaxData":"","image":"","editarCantidad":false,"cantidad":0,"useCssAlterno":false,"id":"I_Cond_2","title":"sin salami","flag":null,"width":0,"height":0,"top":0,"left":0}]
```

That is a representation of this class:

```
public class RootObject
{
 public bool MedidasRelativas { get; set; }
 public string CssClass { get; set; }
 public string CssClassAlterna { get; set; }
 public string CssClassImage { get; set; }
 public string CssClassTitle { get; set; }
 public string CssClassFlag { get; set; }
 public string ajaxRegion { get; set; }
 public string ajaxAction { get; set; }
 public string ajaxActionIzq { get; set; }
 public bool ajaxEnabled { get; set; }
 public int ajaxMethod { get; set; }
 public int ajaxMode { get; set; }
 public string ajaxRegionLoading { get; set; }
 public string ajaxData { get; set; }
 public string image { get; set; }
 public bool editarCantidad { get; set; }
 public int cantidad { get; set; }
 public bool useCssAlterno { get; set; }
 public string id { get; set; }
 public string title { get; set; }
 public object flag { get; set; }
 public int width { get; set; }
 public int height { get; set; }
 public int top { get; set; }
 public int left { get; set; }
}
```

Note: This class was generated at http://json2csharp.com/
My jquery code is this:

```
function actualizarCondiciones(tcLink) {
 $.getJSON(tcLink, function (condiciones) {
     alert(condiciones); //It never reach.
     $.each(condiciones, function (key, val) {
         alert(val);
     });
 });
}
```

The problem is that callback function never reach.

Comment: is port used different than port for page? If so is cross domain. You really need to inspect the request in a browser console to narrow down if problem is server side, path related, or js code problem. Just saying it doesn't work there are far too many variables and unknowns

Comment: No is the same domain. If manually copy url and paste in the browser, it return the json object.

Comment: OK.. need more details about request from browser console. Look for request status, what is being sent and what is being returned

Comment: I'm using ie for debug, where can i find the request status ? ... sorry but just starting with it.

Comment: IE is the least favorable javascript debug browser. F12 in Chrome or install Firebug in Firefox. If stuck with IE it also has debug console. I can't remember if it is an add-on. Try F12. Can also use fiddler

Comment: I'm Trying now in chrome, but the same thisng , it stops at getJSON and pass over there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19950/discussion-between-juan-pablo-gomez-and-charlietfl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chat you included this code:

```
public ActionResult CondicionesMostrar(decimal NumIdTransaccion , decimal NumIdConcepto) 
{ 
    // Se verifica si la session de usuario ya tiene cargada una Id de Transaccion 
    VerificarTransaccion(NumIdTransaccion); 

    //Se seleccionan el item, este ya tiene relacionado el grupo y las condiciones del mismo 
    var item = from i in db.Merlin_ConceptosFacturacion 
    where i.NumIdConcepto == NumIdConcepto 
    select i ; 

    // Se verifica si ya se han agregado algunas condiciones 
    var condiciones = from c in db.Merlin_BR_Condiciones_x_Pedido 
    where c.NumIdTransaccion == NumIdTransaccion 
    select c; 

    ViewBag.condiciones = condiciones.ToList(); 

    return View(item.First()); 
}
```

But you should return a json type, as this:

```
public JsonResult CondicionesMostrar(decimal NumIdTransaccion , decimal NumIdConcepto) 
{ 
    ...
    return Json(item.First()); 
}
```

To test this you can write the following code:

```
public JsonResult CondicionesMostrar(int numIdTransaccion, int numIdConcepto) 
{ 
    return Json(new {NumIdTransaccion = numIdTransaccion, NumIdConcepto = numIdConcepto}); 
}
```

And in javascript:

```
function actualizarCondiciones(tcLink) {
 $.getJSON(tcLink, function (condiciones) {
     console.log(condiciones); // depending on the browser you use, there might not "console.log"
     $.each(condiciones, function (key, val) {
         console.log(key, val);
     });
 }).fail(function() {
     console.log('error', arguments);
 });
}
```

UPDATE for request with GET method:

```
public JsonResult CondicionesMostrar(int numIdTransaccion, int numIdConcepto) 
{ 
    return Json(
          new {NumIdTransaccion = numIdTransaccion, NumIdConcepto = numIdConcepto}
          ,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    ); 
}
```

Comment: Very tks, the change was made now the controller are returning a Json , but very extrange with jQuery side `$.getJSON` doesnt work, but if use `$.post` it works fine.

Comment: because for security is returned only for `JSON` requests for `POST`, if you can user GET request, you need set `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getJSON` incorrectly.  The second parameter is data to pass to the server. You can't just omit it. If no data is expected, just pass `null` or empty object `{}` as second parameter:

```
$.getJSON(tcLink, null, function (condiciones) {
     alert(condiciones); //It never reach.
     $.each(condiciones, function (key, val) {
         alert(val);
     });
 })
```

See [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for details

Comment: You can omit it. Look in the  docs it is optional . Tat's what the `[]` wrapped around param means